# Probability that a Voronoi cell contains exactly k random points

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Consider two independent point processes in the unit square $[0,1]^2$. The two point processes are identically independent and typically  binomial/Poisson. One, say $\Phi^*$, is used to generate a Voronoi tessellation of $N^*$ cells. The other one, $\Phi$ with $N$ points, is used to build the statistics of the counts of points of $\Phi$ in the Voronoi cells associated with $\Phi^*,N^*$.

Gilbert's argument ([Ann. Math. Stat., 1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237872?seq=1)) for a randomly picked given point in plane to be contained in a Voronoi cell of area $s$ is that, known the p.d.f. of cell areas -- be it $f(s)$ --, then the probability of $f(s|X=1)=sE[s]^{-1}f(s)$ where $X$ is a random variable that expresses the count of points in $s$. How can I generalize the argument to any $X$ value? In principle, if I consider $k$ points randomly drawn and independently, I thought of considering $f^k(s|X=1)$, but it does not match simulations. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you give  more  details about the reference you quote?  Voronoi cells, in the simplest case, are associated to a set of points in the plane (or more generally  a metric space). They need not have equal areas.  Please give more details.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu The reference is to the classic Gilbert's paper in [Ann. Math. Stat. 1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237872?seq=1) (in particular the statement is at p. 963, bottom, second paragraph of Section 4).

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I should mention, that in my case I suppose to know $f(s)$ -- the cell area distribution of the random Voronoi tesselation -- the analytical form of this p.d.f. is not known, but can be well approximated by Gamma distributions.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out

Comment: Could you explain the model a bit more? By definition of the Voronoi cells, there is one and only one point in each cell. I'm assuming their seeds are given by a Poisson point process? Are you sampling more points once the domains are chosen? And if so, how?

Comment: @PierrePC I re-elaborated the question, hopefully clarifying the premises. Thanks for pining in.

Comment: @maurizio Thank you for indulging me. In the case where $\Phi$ is Poisson, then $X$ is by definition a Poisson variable, with parameter proportional to the area of the cell. I guess that means $\mathbb P(X=k)=\int f(s)e^{-k}s^k/k!\mathrm ds$, provided the intensity of the process is 1.

Comment: If $\Phi$ is binomial, more or less the same thing happens, $X$ is a binomial with parameters $(n,p)$ where $n$ is the intensity of the global process and $p$ is the the area $s$ of the cell. Here and above I assumed that $s$ meant the area within the square $[0,1]^2$ and, as you said, that $\Phi$ consists of points in the same square.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks. However I think I am confused at this point. The solution that you point out agrees with what I figured out myself in [this post](https://tinyurl.com/ydcrpqm3) few days ago when I also posted this question. But my question was referencing to finding $f(s|X=k)$ starting from $f(s|X=1)$, rather than $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$. The only way I see it is by $\partial_s f_{S,X}(x,s)$ where $f_{S,X}$ is the integrand in $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$. I am wondering if I can find $f_S(s|X=k)$ in another way. $f_S$ is here the probability that given a Voronoi cell of area $s$ it contains $k$ points.

Comment: @maurizio Tell me where I'm wrong. $f(s|X=k)=\mathbb P(X=k|\mathrm{Area}=s)\cdot f(s)/\mathbb P(X=k)$ by Bayes' law, and we know all these probabilities by the above. For instance in the Poisson case of intensity 1, $P(X=k|\mathrm{Area}=s)=e^{-s}s^k/k!$, $f(s)$ is assumed to be known, and $\mathbb P(X^k)=\int f(s)e^{-s}s^k/k!\mathrm ds$.

Comment: @PierrePC Yes. There is nothing wrong with this derivation. But I am wondering if I can find a way to derive $f(s|X=k)$ void of Bayes' law, just by geometry considerations. One way I was thinking of is as following. Gilbert also discusses the probability $\mathbb{P}(b)$ that given two randomly picked points at distance $b$, they belong to the same cell. We know the $f_b(b)$ for two randomly picked points in $[0,1]^2$. Then for $k$ points in the same cell, we can perhaps think of $k-1$ pairs of points, at distance from each other $b_i$...